# RhinoMocks fails when stubbing the same object twice?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I think the code will explain this issue better than my poor title.

`_httpContextBase` is a `HttpContextBase` but I don't imagine that matters. `_httpCookiecollection` is just a `HttpCookieCollection`

```
//Works fine
_httpContextBase.Stub(c => c.Response.Cookies).Return(_httpCookieCollection);

//Fails after attempting to stub the second line. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". First line passes fine.
_httpContextBase.Stub(c => c.Response.Cookies).Return(_httpCookieCollection);
_httpContextBase.Stub(c => c.Request.Cookies).Return(_httpCookieCollection);

//Work around
var responseBaseMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
responseBaseMock.Stub(r => r.Cookies).Return(_httpCookieCollection);
_httpContextBase.Stub(c => c.Response).Return(responseBaseMock);

var requestBaseMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
requestBaseMock.Stub(r => r.Cookies).Return(_httpCookieCollection);
_httpContextBase.Stub(c => c.Request).Return(requestBaseMock);
```

Imagine the above tests are each their own method. Each comment explains what happens when the code below it is run.

The first item works, the second item fails and the third item is my work around. What I want to know is why does the second item fail as I can't seem to figure it out.

---

Stack trace for item 2 (the same stack trace even if lines 1 and 2 are inverted)

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Api.Tests.Client.CookieTests.<>c.<Test>b__12_1(HttpContextBase c) in Api.Tests\Client\CookieTests.cs:line 113
   at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
   at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
   at .Api.Tests.Client.CookieTests.Test() in .Api.Tests\Client\CookieTests.cs:line 113
```

Comment: I don't see any use of Windsor in this question, but perhaps RhinoMocks instead, did you incorrectly title and tag your question? It would also be a good idea to include the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JonathonRossi Oh...I sure did. Thanks Jonathon!

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a bit late to the party and this might not be important to the asker anymore but I will still answer for anyone new to Rhino Mocks.

When mocking with Rhino Mocks, if you call the method multiple times, you need to append `.Repeat.Once()` to each different stub. (`.Once()`) can be replaced with the appropriate number of times that you need to use that response before getting a new response using `.Twice()` or `.Times(x)` where x is replaced with a numeric value for the number of times that you need the call made.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, so I may not be right. But it could be that _httpContextBase.Request is null. If that is the case, and the reason for the NullReferenceException, then it would appear that _httpContextBase.Response is not null, as that doesn't have the same problem.

I don't know that object is set up in your test, but that might be something to look at. Also, have you tried them the other way around? I would guess that it's something to do with .Request, and not that it's the second stub.

I know you haven't asked for it, but I'll also suggest a different approach that I've found useful for mocking complex things like HttpContext. Write an abstraction interface that exposes the parts that you want to use (such as ResponseCookies and RequestCookies). Your implementation of that interface can diretly use the HttpContext members, but your other classes no longer depend on, and you have a very simple interface to mock or stub.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your reply. Response and Request both work on their own. As in if I were to take the first "Works fine" item and change Response to Request this would be fine. If I swap the lines in item 2 then it still crashes on the second line. Your idea advice on the last part is good though!